# I am getting language code error in what API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, whatsapp

Hello  pls has anyone here used the Whatsapp cloud API, I need help in the aspect of creating a template. I have created one, but when I try across via the API, I keep getting template not available in specified language code.

I tried creating another template in another language but still got the same error.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the proper language "code" from the supported list as per the link,
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages/message-templates#supported-languages

Comment: I have done that already  "language":{"code":"en"}, but i still receive this error '(#132001) Template name does not exist in the translation'

Comment: Please provide more details in your question, template create object and send message object.

Comment: @AbrahamZamani did you manage to sort this out, I currently have the same error. I decided to use one of the sample message templates provided here https://web.facebook.com/business/help/722393685250070?_rdc=1&_rdr that's before mine gets approved.
I've used "en", "en_US", "en_GB" non seems to work